# Returning Single Value into Function for Calculation Preparation (SQL/PLSQL)

Tags: sql, function, plsql

I am having trouble with a particular function. What I am trying to do is retrieve a value using this function in order to have it prepared for another function that will perform my desired calculations. Tables involved are: CUSTOMERS_TBL(customer_id PK)  and ORDERS_TBL(order_no PK). I need to pull the 'wallet' value from CUSTOMERS and use that value for the 'wallet_bal' column that is part of the ORDERS_TBL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_wallet_bal(f_id IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER 
    IS wallet_bal NUMBER(5,2);

BEGIN
    SELECT wallet 
    INTO wallet_bal
    FROM customers
    WHERE f_id = customer_id;
    RETURN (wallet_bal);
END;
/
```

My function above retrieves the value I am looking for but instead of returning it into one row, it returns it into all 'wallet_bal' rows.

Comment: have you tried select distinct or select max?

Comment: Good suggestion, I have tried both but that does not change my output.

Comment: How do you call the function exactly?

Comment: Function call looks like this: SELECT get_wallet_bal(5) FROM customers; EDIT: I just realized my error, I thank you Daniel. Using Distinct in the function call gets me my desired result. Its always the little stuff that gets ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function will return exactly one scalar value (or raise an exception), namely the wallet for the customer spiecified by f_id.

in your example:

```
SELECT get_wallet_bal(5) FROM customers
```

you are requesting the wallet for customer with id=5, but as you are querying the customer table, you get the same result as often as there are rows in the customer table. This value will of course always be the same, so with DISTINCT the result set is reduced to one row.

Try, for example

```
SELECT get_wallet_bal(5) FROM DUAL;
```

if you need the wallet for customer 5.

Perhaps you can try the following to help understand the matter:

```
SELECT customer_id, get_wallet_bal(customer_id) FROM customers
```

which will yield the wallets for all customers.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I understood there was a logical error with my query but was not able to fully grasp why my results were returned like that. Your explanation clears up why I received that output. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome. Could you please mark this as answered, so we all can focus on the open questions? Thanks in advance.